# Java error method is undefined for the type Echo

Tags: java, error-handling

I am getting an error on the 11th line of this code "e.results();"
Here is my driver class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class LineScrabbleDriver {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
   String fileName;
   Scanner nameReader = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter a file name");
   fileName = nameReader.nextLine();
   Echo e = new Echo(fileName);
   e.readLines();
   e.results();
  }
}
```

This is the extended class of Echo

```
import java.io.*;
public class LineScrabble extends Echo{
  double max = 0.0;
  String bestWord = "";
  int lineNumer = 0;
  public LineScrabble(String f) throws IOException {
    super(f);
  }
//scrabbles
int[] scrabbles = {1,3,3,2,1,4,2,4,1,8,5,1,3,1,1,3,10,1,1,1,1,4,4,8,4,10};
//process the given line
public void processLine(String s) {
  s.toLowerCase();
  int score = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++){
    char ch = s.charAt(i);
    if(Character.isLetter(ch)){
      int pos = ch - 'a';
      score += scrabbles[pos];
      }
    }
  if(score > max){
    max = score;
    bestWord = s;
  }
}
//displays the winner and score
public void results() {
System.out.println("Winner: " + bestWord);
System.out.println("score: " + max/bestWord.length());
}
}
```

Here is the Echo class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

  public class Echo{
    String fileName; // external file name
    Scanner scan; // Scanner object for reading from external file

    public Echo(String f) throws IOException
    {
     fileName = f;
     scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));
   }

   public void readLines(){ // reads lines, hands each to processLine
     while(scan.hasNext()){
       processLine(scan.nextLine());
     }
     scan.close();
  }

  public void processLine(String line){ // does the real processing work
     System.out.println(line);
   }
 }
```

I'm not quite sure why it is giving me a undefined type error. I'm new to java programming. please help!

Comment: Because `results` isn't defined in Echo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using the original `Echo` and not a `LineScrabble`, I think you wanted something like -

```
// Echo e = new Echo(fileName); //
LineScrabble e = new LineScrabble(fileName);
e.readLines();
e.results(); // <-- Echo does not have results() you could add it there, or 
             // use LineScrabble.
```